# Is there a way to git clone multiple .git repositories at one shot, all exisiting in same folder in remote machine?

Tags: linux, git

I have a git machine, where there is a folder: git:/opt/git/third_party> 
Inside third_party there are multiple .git repoitories.

I wish to clone all the .git inside third_party at one shot:

Something like:
    git clone kingsmasher1@git:/opt/git/third_party/*.git

Is it possible?

Comment: If you don't know the name, then no. If you do, you can use a loop or shell expansion (e.g. with bash `third_party/{repo1,repo2,other_repo}.git`)

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative approach**

You can use [mr](https://github.com/joeyh/myrepos) tool. With `mr` you can specify a file, where you list all of your repositories. Via `mr checkout` you'll clone all configured repos and with `mr update` you'll update all of them etc.